# Extract multiple occurrences of text within a $ sign in a single cell

Tags: excel

I have a file where the data contains multiple variable references within a cell where the variables(Ex: XXXXX) are enclosed within $ signs like $XXXXX$. The cell value looks something like this:

Ex:

```
This is a requirement for $XXXXX$ where in data is fetched from $YYYYYY$ and needs to be placed under $ZZZZZ$
```

Expected output:

```
XXXXXX
YYYYYY
ZZZZZZ
```

I tried the excel MID and FIND function but open to a VBA solution.

N/A

Comment: In your data, does $XXXXX$ always be the first 2 dollar sign, $YYYYYY$ always be the second 2 dollar signs and always be the third 2 dollar signs?

Comment: I wrote something complex and have a temporary solution.

Comment: @PeicongChen In my data, all that i need is always enclosed within pair of $'s.

Comment: Look into Regular Expressions

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Excel 2016 or higher or Office365, then you can use the [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) to do this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$",REPT(" ",LEN(D2))),LEN($D2)*(ROW($1:$30)*2-1)+1,LEN($D2))),))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in, for example, `A10`, you can use this (Excel 2013+):

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A$10," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[starts-with(text(),'$')]"),ROWS($1:1)),"$",""),"")
```

and fill down until blanks are returned.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I t might look complex, but this solved my issue. Now this formula can handle up to 25 variables in Excel.

> `=IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",1)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",2))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",1))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",3)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",4))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",3))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",5)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",6))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",5))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",7)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",8))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",7))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",9)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",10))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",9))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",11)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",12))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",11))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",13)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",14))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",13))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",15)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",16))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",15))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",17)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",18))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",17))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",19)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",20))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",19))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",21)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",22))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",21))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",23)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",24))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",23))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",25)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",26))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",25))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",27)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",28))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",27))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",29)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",30))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",29))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",31)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",32))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",31))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",33)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",34))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",33))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",35)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",36))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",35))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",37)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",38))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",37))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",39)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",40))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",39))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",41)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",42))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",41))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",43)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",44))-FIND(">{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",43))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",45)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",46))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",45))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",47)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",48))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",47))),"")
>   &CHAR(10)&IFERROR(MID($D2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",49)),1+FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","}}}",50))-FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE($D2,"$","{{{",49))),"")`